# Testing Stripe payment Publishable Key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following the stripe instruction (see below link) regarding "Supporting a Variable Amount in Checkout". I'm creating test payment page. I'm getting an error calling my Test Publishable Key.
 
[Supporting a Variable Amount in Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/variable-amount-checkout)

I've added my test_key within config/initializers/stripe.rb 
[image: stribe.rb]

But I'm still getting an error asking to set a valid publishable key. I am certain that my test-keys are accurate. Am I doing something wrong? I followed the instruction step by step without any luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem by adding entry to my secrets.yml file, that is where I put my test_publishable key, then modified my stripe.rb.